# Angular js Child view not update data in parent view outside controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular js UI-Router :
header Controller
Parent view :->Child view 
Footer Controller

Footer controller have time out function to show time text in footer.

while working in parent view footer getting update .

but while working in child view footer text time is not updating.

but timeout function is working background if i click on any parent view it reflecting

Comment: It is hard to help without reproduction code example

Comment: can u provide demo code on https://plnkr.co/edit/